# android - remove album art from showing in the gallery

Tags: android, image, gallery, albumart

We store album art for tracks on the SD card in its own directory for instance "sdcard/app/images/" however those images are showing up in the Gallery. How do we disable this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place a dummy (blank) file called `.nomedia` in the your /sdcard/app/images directory. This should prevent it being included in media scans.

Not sure if it has an immediate effect. If not, try dismounting then mounting the SD card to trigger a fresh media scan.

Comment: this did not work. I even restarted the phone still showing. We were thinking to move those images to the secure card location which should help but still...

Comment: ok the way I did that was I took a .nomedia file from the native OS and added that into my app folder on the SD card. That stopped all media files showing up everywhere. But me creating that file myself did not help. Thank you for suggestion.